# How do I reload persisted workflow in Idle state after the WorkflowRuntime was restarted? (newbie question)

Tags: workflow-foundation

I am planing to create long lasting workflows which I would like to persist when they become idle. However, meanwhile they are in Idle state, the WorkflowRuntime might be restarted.

The question is: How do I create the WorkflowRuntime in a way, that it will reload all stored idle workflows?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The WorkflowRuntime is WF3 not WF4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WorkflowRuntime will make sure that workflows with a expired DelayActivity will get reloaded. If you are using custom async acitivities it is your responsibility to reload the workflow and queue the message.